# Why my keyboard & trackpad of macbook Pro Retina 2015 13'' is not responding? Even PRAM does not help to reboot it?

Tags: keyboard, cursor, unresponsive

I am newly using MacBook Pro Retina but soon I am facing the problem of not opening the login screen. I hear the start up chime & tried for PRAM (using Command + Alt +P +R keys) as per the suggestion. It helped me sometimes but it too is not helping me anymore. The cursor appears at the top left corner in the grey screen soon after apple logo appears but does not move & I can't login to the system. The language to be chosen appears but the drop down list does not move by the keyboard arrows. However, I can move from the external keyboard. Please guide me how can I reboot my MacBook. It is not opening for 2 days nearly.

Comment: Please edit your question with this info : Does it boot up all the way to the desktop?  When you plug in an external keyboard and mouse, do they work normally?  When you boot from an external USB, what do you see?  Is the device still on warranty?  Are you near an Apple Store?

Answer (score 0):

Am I correct in reading that command-option-P-R no longer fixes the issue or the sequence itself no longer restarts the computer?

The distinction is important as you may have a hardware issue. If it is a hardware issue the extent depends on what year Retina and what size it is. Some models have the trackpad, keyboard and power button going directly to the logic board while some have the keyboard loop through the trackpad (if I remember correctly, it's basically opposite of how the MacBook Air would be internally).

Hopefully it's just the sequence not fixing the issue because then it sounds like a software issue (possible reinstall of the operating system).

One way to test is to power on and hold the option key. It should show a row of icons showing what you can boot from. If you don't see one listed as Recovery then restart one more time and hold command-R. This will boot you to the recovery disk, see if the pointer and keyboard work there. If they do then a reinstall is looking to be the likely solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. As per your suggestion, I tried it but is not responding. It's Mac Book Pro Retina 2015 13" sent from US bought around 4/5 months earlier but I do not have the purchase invoice here. Do you think I can claim for warranty? More importantly, I had my task saved in it & had not taken any backups & they are urgent to be reported. So, how can I extract those data from it even if it is not working provided hardware components should remain intact. Please suggest.

Comment: Given that the external USB devices worked and the nvram/pram reset did not then yes, make arrangements for warranty repair.  Backup your data first!  This sounds like either an IPD cable and trackpad or possibly including the top case. My memory on the internal layout is fading so I'm not 100% sure which components.

Comment: Thank You!  After a long back, I would like to inform that even after the software update, the internal keyboard & trackpad is not responding. However, it is normal with external mouse & keyboard. In external keyboard, there is no "Command" button, do you know which button is the substitute for that action? How can I format my macbook? I am not sure whether formatting will help me or not but can I try? Hope for the proper suggestion!!

Comment: The windows key should sub for it. If it doesn't then try the left Alt key. I really don't think a reformat will resolve this issue, it seems like hardware. It would be your best bet to boot up, use the external mouse and keyboard to backup anything you may care about, then bring it into an Apple Store or local authorized Apple service place for repair. The reset we had you do before should have brought the internal devices back if there wasn't an issue with one of the components. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is not clear from your description, but you should be pressing the command-option-P-R keys BEFORE the mac starts its boot process ie BEFORE the start-up chime, if you are only pressing them after then it is too late and the clearing pram process won't work.

Just by the way the name is now NVRAM.

As another option you can set the mac to be an external drive for another mac using a thunderbolt cable and be able to access the contents for backup or copying.

I had to do this between my macbook pro and my Imac when the graphics card failed in the Imac - worked flawlessly.

Comment: Thank You so much Sir! I have tested it by using the external keyboard & external mouse & it's working properly. So, can you guess what might be the probable problem in this case? Thank you once again Sir!